# How can search escaped string from a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is while insertion I'm using `addslashes()` function then the string is inserted as `kadavath\'s` , but at time of select I'm using `LIKE` operator at that time result is empty. Please help me.

Comment: Use PDO instead of mysql_ functions, you won't need to escape anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is how your data looks in the database:

> kadavath\'s

then you're doing something wrong.

The right function to escape data for `mysql_query()` queries is `mysql_real_escape_string()`. There is no need for addslashes(), in adding that breaks your data, as we see here.

Comment: I tried with mysql_real_escape_string() at that time also slash is adding.

Comment: @Pramod I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: while using mysql_real_escape_string() also slash is inserting to db.

Comment: @Pramod then you may have Magic Quotes enabled. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php